# Reload section of UICollectionView and preserve scroll position

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have a horizontal `UICollectionView` with several sections, each containing several cells as follows:

Section 0: one cell to cancel selection.
Section 1: recently selected items.
Section 2 and beyond: each section has several items that can be selected.

When a cell from section 2 or later is selected, a copy of that item is inserted to the start section 1 in the data source, and I want to reload section 1 to reflect the updated recent items. But, I want to preserve the scroll position. I've tried:

`[collectionView reloadSections:setWithIndex1]` and
`[collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:arrayWithAllSection1IndexPaths]`
I've tried using `[collectionView performBatchUpdates:]`, but everything I've tried makes the scroll offset reset to the beginning of the collection view. I've tried a sanity check by starting a fresh app with a basic collection view and reloading a section using `reloadSections`, and it has the desired behavior of **not** resetting the scroll offset. But doing the same in my existing codebase does, undesirably, reset the offset.

I've poured over my `collectionView`-related code looking for `reloadData`'s, `setContentOffsets`'s, and similar things, but for the life of me I can't find what's causing it. Is there anything I'm missing that could be resetting the scroll position after an update?

Comment: Just calculate new offset and set it.

Comment: I tried that. It causes it flicker back to the start and then to the newly set offset.

Comment: Do it with `animation = NO` and in `[UIVIew performWithoutAnimation:]` block

Comment: If flickers less, but it's still there. Breaking at `reloadSections` I can see it set's the content offset changes to 0,0. But in my sanity check app it does not. Any idea why that is?

Comment: Try just `reloadData` instead of `reloadSections`

Comment: `reloadData` reloads the whole collection and resets the content offset.

Comment: It doesn't reset content offset.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are OK with doing it without any animation I would do as follows:

- start with disabling animations

```swift
UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
```

- before inserting a new item (cell), store the value of visible rect for the selected cell

```swift
let selectedCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
let visibleRect = collectionView.convert(collectionView.bounds, to: selectedCell)
```

- perform the insertion and when it's finished, check what is the new visible rect for the selected cell, compare it to the old value and add their difference to collectionView's contentOffset.

```swift
selectedObjects.insert(allObjects[indexPath.item], at: 0)
collectionView.performBatchUpdates({

   // INSERTING NEW ITEM
   let indexPathForNewItem = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 1)
   collectionView.insertItems(at: [indexPathForNewItem])
}) { (finished) in

   // GETTING NEW VISIBLE RECT FOR SELECTED CELL
   let updatedVisibleRect = collectionView.convert(collectionView.bounds, to: selectedCell)

   // UPDATING COLLECTION VIEW CONTENT OFFSET
   var contentOffset = collectionView.contentOffset
   contentOffset.x = contentOffset.x + (visibleRect.origin.x - updatedVisibleRect.origin.x)
   collectionView.contentOffset = contentOffset
}
```

- Finish by enabling animations back

```swift
UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
```

---

I tried it on a simple collection view adjusted to the behaviour you described. 
Here's the whole implementation (collecionView is in the storyboard, so if you want to give my solution a test, don't forget to connect the outlet.)

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    let reuseIdentifier = "cell.reuseIdentifier"

    var allObjects: [UIColor] = [.red, .yellow, .orange, .purple, .blue]
    var selectedObjects: [UIColor] = []


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.collectionView.delegate = self
        self.collectionView.dataSource = self
        self.collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: self.reuseIdentifier)
    }
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        switch section {
        case 0: return 1
        case 1: return selectedObjects.count
        case 2: return allObjects.count
        default: return 0
        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: self.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)

        switch indexPath.section {
        case 0: cell.contentView.backgroundColor = .black
        case 1: cell.contentView.backgroundColor = selectedObjects[indexPath.item]
        case 2: cell.contentView.backgroundColor = allObjects[indexPath.item]
        default: break
        }

        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 150, height: collectionView.frame.size.height)
    }
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        collectionView.deselectItem(at: indexPath, animated: false)

        switch indexPath.section {
        case 0:
            self.selectedObjects.removeAll()
            collectionView.reloadData()
        case 2:
            if selectedObjects.contains(allObjects[indexPath.item]) {
                break
            } else {
                // SOLUTION //
                UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
                let selectedCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
                let visibleRect = collectionView.convert(collectionView.bounds, to: selectedCell)

                selectedObjects.insert(allObjects[indexPath.item], at: 0)
                collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
                    let indexPathForNewItem = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 1)
                    collectionView.insertItems(at: [indexPathForNewItem])
                }) { (finished) in
                    let updatedVisibleRect = collectionView.convert(collectionView.bounds, to: selectedCell)

                    var contentOffset = collectionView.contentOffset
                    contentOffset.x = contentOffset.x + (visibleRect.origin.x - updatedVisibleRect.origin.x)
                    collectionView.contentOffset = contentOffset
                }
                UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
                // END OF SOLUTION //
            }

        default:
            break
        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 10, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT**

I just also tried replacing

```swift
let indexPathForNewItem = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 1)
collectionView.insertItems(at: [indexPathForNewItem])
```

with

```swift
collectionView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: 1))
```

and it also works just fine, without any flickering, so it's up to you which is more convenient for you.

Comment: This totally solves the issue - thank you for the thorough answer! I think I'm gonna tweak it so that if section 1 is visible, it will animate, so that as cells get added it doesn't appear sudden. But if section 1 is entirely offscreen, then I'll turn off the animation and won't tweak the content offset.

Comment: I have a similar problem but I'm using `UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource`. Whenever I call `.apply(snapshot:)` on my dataSource, the collectionView scrolls to the top. The interesting thing in my case is I might add cells before or after the currently visible cell, but I still want the viewport to stay put.

Answer (score 2):

**IMPORTANT!**

If you want to preserve `UICollectionView` scroll position when you fetch new items, it is better to insert the new items instead of reloading the entire section (or maybe the entire list!)..

But the trick here is to set the size of each item (or cell) to avoid jumping behavior (or flickers):

1. Inherit your `ViewController` from `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` and implement the `sizeForItemAt`

   ```
   class myViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, 
       UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

       // Your core functions goes here

       func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
           return CGSize(width: ITEM_WIDTH, height: ITEM_HEIGHT)
       }

   }
   ```
2. Insert the items:

   ```
   for i in dictionary {

       items.append(i)

       collectionView.performBatchUpdates({

           collectionView.insertItems(at: [IndexPath(item: items.count - 1, section: 0)])

           }, completion: { [] (_) in

       })
   }
   ```

Comment: though it's quite overhead to track the index of item need to be inserted or deleted, I found this approach better.